# Vert.x JDBC client: Could not load the required implementation

Tags: java, jdbc, vert.x, vertx4

I'm trying to connect to a database with the vert.x JDBC client:

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.*;
import io.vertx.jdbcclient.JDBCConnectOptions;
import io.vertx.jdbcclient.JDBCPool;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.*;

public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

     @Override
     public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {

        JDBCPool pool = JDBCPool.pool(
                vertx,
                new JDBCConnectOptions()
                .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://some_ip")
                .setUser("user")
                .setPassword("password"),
                new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(16)
                );
        pool
          .query("SELECT * FROM test")
          .execute()
          .onFailure(e -> {
              System.out.println(e.toString());
          })
    }
}
```

This gives me the result:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not load the required implementation
```

I assume, that this is caused by line 53 [here](https://github.com/agroal/agroal/blob/master/agroal-api/src/main/java/io/agroal/api/AgroalDataSource.java).

However, I don't really understand what the code there is doing.

Complete stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not load the required implementation
    at io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource.from(AgroalDataSource.java:53)
    at io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource.from(AgroalDataSource.java:33)
    at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.AgroalCPDataSourceProvider.getDataSource(AgroalCPDataSourceProvider.java:73)
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.JDBCClientImpl.createDataSource(JDBCClientImpl.java:274)
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.JDBCClientImpl.lambda$getDataSourceHolder$6(JDBCClientImpl.java:256)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:160)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:158)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.agroal.pool.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource.from(AgroalDataSource.java:49)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Sorry, if the question is stupid, but how can I get the complete stacktrace?
If I don't include the `.onFailure()`, it fails without error. What I posted, is the complete error I get with the code written above.

Comment: Replace `System.out.println(e.toString());` with `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Can you make sure the MS SQL Server JDBC driver is present in the classpath?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I added the Stacktrace to the question

Answer (score 1):

The error can be resolved by adding

```
  implementation group: 'io.agroal', name: 'agroal-pool', version: '1.0'
```

to the `build.gradle`.

Comment: Exactly. This solve the problem. You can check in Maven repository for latest version, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.agroal/agroal-pool
(2.0)

`implementation group: 'io.agroal', name: 'agroal-pool', version: '2.0'`
or
`implementation 'io.agroal:agroal-pool:2.0'`